# why button onClick is not working in ejs file?

Tags: ejs

Why isn't my onclick function working

```
<%- include("partials/header") -%>


  <button onClick=<%= function(){ return console.log("hello")}; %>
  type="submit" name="optionSelect" value="man" >man</button><br>

  <%- include("partials/footer")-%>
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it you have 3 errors, 1- `<%` this symbol is used to execute javascript code on html file, and `<%=` this symbol to pass data from a javascript file to an html file, 2- your `;` is in the wrong place, and 3- you need a closing tag for the button.

Try this solution below, see if it works:

```
<%- include("partials/header") -%>
<button onClick= <%function(){return console.log("hello");}%> type="submit" name="optionSelect" value="man" >man</button>
<%- include("partials/footer")-%>
```